# Why does my SSH keys only work sometimes?

Tags: ssh, terminal, passwords, ssh-keys

I have setup SSH keys and Gentoo Keychain for quick and easy login to a server I sometimes access.

What's weird is that keybased login works sometimes while other times it falls back to password. And this might even happen in the same terminal/terminal session (that is, I open a terminal, ssh to this server and logging in using SSH keys works fine. A few hours later, the connection has dropped and I just go back one line in my local command history and try to open a new SSH connection but this time I am required to enter the password. Next time I repeat this process in the same terminal, keys again work as expected.)

A verbose log from a failed login:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/db/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6zeoJz3P+3s6pfwTGPG8Rmc8kcJ8CKHlJnm54ugj1K4 agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/db/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/db/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/db/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

What's going on here?

Update:

This is a log from the same client connecting to the same server an hour later. This time the key exchange was successful.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/db/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6zeoJz3P+3s6pfwTGPG8Rmc8kcJ8CKHlJnm54ugj1K4 agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/db/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6zeoJz3P+3s6pfwTGPG8Rmc8kcJ8CKHlJnm54ugj1K4 agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server.com ([123.456.78.90]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5870 forwarded to remote address smtp.server.com:587
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5870.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5870.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
Linux triton 4.9.0-11-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) i686
```

Comment: Please review your `sshd_config`'s `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`, as `ssh-rsa` appears to be missing since OpenSSH is not checking for an RSA public key

Comment: @JW0914 I don't have access to the config of the sshd. Do you mean that the sshd switches among different configs?? Isn't that weird?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I didn't realize you edited your question... it appears there was some kind of error on the server's side, so the server's logs will need to be checked to determine what the issue was that occurred... you cannot troubleshoot this via the client log.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The server mounts my home directory using Kerberos. When I log in with password a new Kerberos ticket is issued, but it only lasts for 24 hours. During these 24 h I can login with ssh keys (because my home directory is mounted and sshd therefore can read my ssh key) but after 24 h my home directory is unmounted and when I then try to open an ssh connection sshd is unable to read my ssh keys.